# How to grep the word after - bash?

Tags: bash, grep

Trying to get the MAC address, a4:1f:72:6e:2a:cf, from a result like this (see below) to be saved in a variable, $NewMAC. The way this happens is an arp-scan get outputted to at a text file, and this is the result.

```
Interface: eth2, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 1 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)

192.168.1.100    a4:1f:72:6e:2a:cf    (Unknown)

1 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 1 hosts scanned in 0.143 seconds (6.99 hosts/sec). 1 responded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/^[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9][.][0-9]+/ {print $2}' arp-scan-output.txt
```

Comment: This one WORKED!!! Thank you! One a side note, is there a way to make the letters of the MAC address CAPS?

Comment: @user3525621: Replace `{print $2}` with `{print toupper($2)}` or append `| tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E ' ([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2} '
```

This selects lines containing the ethernet address.  If you have GNU `grep`, you can use `-o` to select just the matching text.  If the blanks matter (you absolutely can't have them), then you have to be sloppier (not look for the blanks) or use less standard notations such as `\b` to mean beginning/end of word.

Hence:

```
NewMAC=$(arp-scan ... | grep -E -o '\b([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}\b')
```

If you don't have GNU `grep`, you could use `| awk '{print $2}'` to print the second column of output.

```
NewMAC=$(arp-scan ... | grep -E ' ([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2} ' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: +1 for the background info; `-o` and `\b` work in FreeBSD (OSX) `grep` as well.